# image upload with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

I want to use ajax to upload image.
In this module:

1. On clicking `browse` and selecting image, it will be uploaded and displayed over file field.
2. After adding title and description, and clicking on the button, that image will be displayed below and upper image field will be blank

Comment: Could you please post your current HTML / Javascript

Comment: What did you try, what didn't work, and where's the faulty code? I'm terribly sorry for having to ask, but I seem to have misplaced my crystal ball..

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload files through AJAX. You need to work with IFRAMEs or a Flash-Based uploader.

Comment: I would prefer the use of iframe, since we're not built to do flash.

Comment: … which are Ajax. Ajax is not XHR. XHR is just the most common way to implement Ajax.

Comment: Firefox >= 3 and Chrome >= 2 support XHR uploads.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy you can upload images with the ajax function in Jquery in atleast the lates version of chrome.

HTML:

```
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     <input type="file" name="image"/>
     <button type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
       url: window.location.pathname,
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
       }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

This script will send a post request with the created file data to the current page through Ajax. You can change the destination obviously through changing the url parameter.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the form element in jquery, only to read it again? `$(this)[0]` === `this`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JQuery plugin for uploading an image.

May be http://www.uploadify.com/

This will give an idea how to do it.

Comment: @piemesons Its working on my system using IE 8. please make sure you had flash player installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a handle on the server side.. here is a small function and example on how to implement the 'iframe hack' in javascript.

**html**

```
<form name="image-upload">
<input type="file" name="image" /></br>
<button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
<div id="upload-results"></div>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
var fileUpload = function(form /* HTMLElement */, action /* Form Action URL */, callback /* Callback function */) {
    /* vars */
    var atribs = {
        "target": "upload_iframe",
        "action": action,
        "method": "post",
        "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
        "encoding": "multipart/form-data"
    }, iframe;
    /* iframe listener */
    var ilistener = function() {
        var results;
        listener.remove(this, 'load', ilistener);
        if( 'contentDocument' in this ) {
            results = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if ( 'contentWindow' in this ) {
            results = this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if ( 'document' in this ) {
            results = this.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else {
            throw "i'm dead jim :/";
        }
        callback.apply(this,[results]); // call the callback, passing the results
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this); // remove the iframe
    };

    /* create the iframe */
    form.parentNode.appendChild(FragBuilder([{"tagName": "iframe","id": "upload_iframe","name": "upload_iframe","style": {"height": "0","width": "0","border": "0"}}]));
    /* collect the iframe back */
    iframe = By.id('upload_iframe');
    /* set the form properties */
    for( var attr in atribs ) {
        if( attr in form ) {
            form[attr] = atribs[attr];
        }
    }
    /* attach the event listener to the iframe */
    listener.add(iframe, 'load', ilistener);
    /* submitting the form */
    form.submit();
};

// get the form, and the results area
var form = document.forms['image-upload'], results = By.id('upload-results');
// listen for the form submit, capture it, and run the iframe upload.
listener.add(form, 'submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    results.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
    fileUpload(this, 'server.php' /* really anything */, function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
            results.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
    });
});
```

Please note: for simplicity purposes I have used the following utilities. 
https://github.com/rlemon/FragBuilder.js DocumentFragment builder from JSON input.
https://gist.github.com/2172100 event listener, and By utility functions.
*these are both easily removed.

Comment: I realize this is three years past the fact.. but I came upon this while searching. So I figure others may as well. Here is you're 2012 answer

Comment: I'm getting an error "ReferenceError: By is not defined" "var form = document.forms['image-upload'], results = By.id('upload-results');"

Comment: Utility functions need to be included as well.  see the notes below the code. or change By.id to document.getElementById