# How to receive data, sent from the browser using XMLHttpRequest, in server-side (php)?

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I cannot understand how to get blobs from XMLHttpRequest in my PHP script.
I have such code in JS:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();          // create instance

var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];     // get File Object from <input type=file />. It is picture

req.open("POST", “uploader.php”, true); // make request

req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);   set request headers
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", file.size);

req.send(file);                 // send request with file-blob

if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      alert("result = " + req.responseText);
}
```

I understand how to send the blob to the server, but don’t understand how and from where to get it there. I tried to use `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_FILES` global arrays but they don’t have any files. I even tried to add `file` to the url like this:

```
req.open("POST", “uploader.php?file=” + file, true);
```

It’s not the solution either.

Reading answers here I found that I can get raw binary data using `php://input`. I tried and yes I got some raw data. Going to examine this solution through and through. But want to ask is this the only way? If not, what are the others? And which one is the most right then?

Also, when I set header `("Content-Length", file.size)` the `console.log` shows error and says “Refused to set unsafe header “Content-Length”. Isn't this header necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the post below:

[image upload with ajax and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558838/image-upload-with-ajax-and-php)

You can't really upload a blob via the XmlHttpRequest, but you can create an AJAX like feel with hidden iframes.

It looks like there are some JQuery plugins that may help you out as well.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your header:

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```